# Gcc/ld warning "liba" needed by "libb", not found, yet part of rpath

Tags: gcc, ld

I'm getting some warnings from `ld` about libraries that aren't found, but as far as I can tell it should be finding them. For example:

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libleaf_util.so, needed by build/libleaf_lang.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

This happens when I link the executable `build/unit_test` that includes `build/libleaf_lang.so`, as part of the command line(1). The linking is adding `rpath=$ORIGIN` to the executable and all the libraries, including the library `build/libleaf_lang.so`. If I do ldd on `build/libleaf_lang.so` it is able to find the library in question:

`libleaf_util.so => /home/src/leaf/misc/build/libleaf_util.so (0x00007fd7c2f90000)`

That would seem to indicate the required library is found. So why do I get the warning?

*Note this appears to only happen when I link using the path to the shared library, `build/libleaf_lang.so`. If I link by name `-lleaf_lang`, as I do for another executable, I do not get the warning.*

---

(1) `g++ -o build/unit_test -z origin -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN build/boost_test_main.o build/test/expr_conversion_test.o build/test/statement_test.o build/test/expr_type_test.o build/test/full_type_test.o build/test/gmp_test.o build/test/intr_type_parse_test.o build/test/lambda_test.o build/test/number_test.o build/test/object_holder_test.o build/test/parse_test.o build/test/scope_test.o build/test/source_test.o build/test/type_converter_cost.o build/test/type_converter_fixate.o build/test/type_converter_function_call.o build/test/type_converter_match_function.o build/test/type_converter_parameterize_type.o build/test/type_converter_test.o build/test/type_converter_unify.o build/test/type_identifier_constrain.o build/test/type_identifier_determine.o build/test/type_identifier_expand.o build/test/type_identifier_get_spec.o build/test/type_identifier_infer.o build/test/unicode_test.o build/libleaf_lang.so build/libleaf_parser.so build/libleaf_util.so build/libleaf_runner.so build/libleaf_ir.so build/libleaf_ir_llvm.so -Lbuild/build/lib -Lsrc/build/lib -L/usr/lib -Lbuild -Lsrc -L/opt/llvm/install/lib -L/usr/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_program_options -lrt -ldl -lboost_regex -lLLVM-3.8 -lgmp -lgmpxx -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system`

Comment: Maybe try `-rpath=\"$ORIGIN\"`...

Comment: @l'L'l The rpath bit is working. The resulting libraries/executables have it set correctly.  The command is copied from the build process output, not what is given directly to bash.

Comment: Which platform/OS are you using?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of `ld` from binutils ignores `$ORIGIN` in RPATH:

- [$ORIGIN in shared library's rpath not used to find library dependencies at link time](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16936)
- [DSO1 needed by DSO2 linked into executable not found without -rpath-link, even though DT_RPATH and -rpath would find it](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20535)

This functionality was added to [binutils 2.28](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;h=199fa1b7089d7f7438b087fa30504ea5a590f561).

Comment: I guess that's it, as I'm using 2.26.1.  I wonder why it's just a warning in this case.

Comment: In most cases, `ld` does not actually need access to the shared object when preparing an object for dynamic linking, which is why a hard error may have deemed excessive. (Traditionally, ELF linking does not perform a lot of error checking.)